# No puedo pasar un arreglo de estructuras a una función en C

Tags: c++, c, array, funciones, estructuras-de-datos

Me da el siguiente error al querer pasar el vector a una funcion :

> [Error] could not convert '(profesores*)(& prfsr)' from 'profesores*' to 'profesores'.

Paso el codigo para ver que esta mal, llevo un rato intentandolo resolver , incluso pasarlo con punteros y aun asi me sigue dando error, de antemano gracias por la ayuda.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct profesores{
    char nombre[30];
    char sexo[30];
    int edad;
};

void promed(profesores,int);
void joven(profesores, int);
int menu();

int main() {
    profesores prfsr[100];
    int n, opcion;
    float promedio;
    printf("-------BIENVENIDO AL REGISTRO DE LOS PROFESORES-------\n");
    printf("Cuantos profesores desea registrar?\n");
    scanf("%d", & n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Introduzca el nombre\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(prfsr[i].nombre);
        printf("Introduzca el genero\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(prfsr[i].sexo);
        printf("Introduzca la edad\n");
        scanf("%d", & prfsr[i].edad);
        system("cls");

        if (i == n - 1) {
            printf("Profesores Registrados Exitosamente\n");
        }
    }
    promed(prfsr, n);
    opcion = menu();

    switch (opcion) {
    case 1:
        break;
    }
}

int menu(){
    int opcion;
    printf("Seleccione una opcion\n");
    printf("1....Nombre del profesor mas joven del registro\n");
    printf("2....Nombre del profesor con mas edad\n");
    printf("3....No. de Profesores con edad mayor al promedio\n");
    printf("4....No. de Profesores con edad menor al promedio\n");
    scanf("%d",&opcion);
    return opcion;  
}

void joven(profesores registro[],int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        registro[i].edad;
        
    }
}

void promed(profesores promedio[],int n){
    float prom=0;
    int suma; 
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        suma += promedio[i].edad; 
    }   
        
    prom = suma/n;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Es muy importante que aclares si es c o c++

Comment: La confusión probablemente se deba al nombre que le pusiste a la estructura. `profesores` en realidad representa un solo profesor.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes esto mal

```
void promed(profesores,int);
void joven(profesores, int);
```

Deberias ponerlo así

```
void promed(profesores*,int);
void joven(profesores*, int);
```

Y las funciones declararlas de una de estas dos formas si es en C

```
void promed(struct profesores *p,int i)
{
 ///código
}
void joven(struct profesores p[],int i)
{
 ///código
}
```

Y si es en C++ tambien puedes hacerlo así

```
void promed(profesores *p,int i)
{
 ///código
}
void joven(profesores p[],int i)
{
 ///código
}
```

Comment: Lo estoy haciendo en c, ya lo puse como dijiste y si me compila , muchas gracias pero tengo unas dudas, en el prototipo de la funcion por que se le pone el " * " despues del tipo de la estructura y tambien cuando se declarara en c se le tiene que poner struct en la funcion antes del tipo ah y al mandar las estructuras desde el main deberia hacerlo con & o directamente el nombre de la variable como cualquier otro tipo de funcion.

Comment: El " * " se pone porque es un vector (array) el parametro que estás declarando... lo de poner poner **struct** antes del tipo es algo que no sabría explicarte con profundidad, tal vez alguien con conocimientos mas amplios que yo sepa, y sinceramente no le veo mucho sentido, creo que por eso mismo en C++ no lo usan. Se usa como cualquier otra variable, el '&' se usa cuando quieres pasar la dirección de la memoria de esa variable (un puntero) normalmente  porque quieres modificar su valor dentro de la función. PS: No te olvides de votar las respuestas que te sean útiles y también las inuteles.